# Comunicação TCP/IP com impressora Markem9030

Tags: tcpclient

Boa tarde pessoal,
Tenho um programa em c# que abre uma conexão socket usando TCP/IP e escreve alguns dados... ao ler as respostas ele recebe alguns bytes que ao converter em HEX ele fica assim:

FF FD 03 FF FB 03 FF FB 01

Alguém sabe o que significa?

Em suma, se estivesse tudo certo o device no qual estou conectando deveria retornar 06 em HEX.

Estou tentando comunicar com uma impressora Markem 9030 com interface de rede. Nela ja esta configurado para comunicação TCP Socket...

Obrigado,

Comment: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm > dá `ÿýÿûÿû`

Comment: Ja tinha convertido dessa forma tb... mas não faço ideia do que esses caracteres significam... rs